# WPF: change binding properties for multiple controls

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I'd like that all the `Text` bindings for the `TextBox`es in my `UserControl` to have `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, and `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True`

How to do it ?

I can think of a solution: use another class for bindings (a class inheriting `Binding`) but maybe there is another solution, maybe using a style or template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a style or template, since a binding is not a `FrameworkElement`. But your idea of a class inheriting `Binding` should work fine, I've done the same before for a similar problem